# How to create timer in React-hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How i can create animated timer using React-hooks

[Here is complete code what i had tried](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-dust-0o1jt?file=/src/App.js)

Basically  i was trying Displays the progress of time remaining as an animated ring.
But somehow i am getting failed in it

I just followed this blog for creating animated timer `https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-animated-countdown-timer-with-html-css-and-javascript/`

```
  function setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft) {
    const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
    console.log(dataFromDiv);
    if (timeLeft <= alert.threshold) {
      dataFromDiv.current
        .querySelectorAll("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .classList.remove(warning.color);
      dataFromDiv.current
        .querySelectorAll("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .classList.add(alert.color);
    } else if (timeLeft <= warning.threshold) {
      dataFromDiv.current
        .querySelectorAll("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .classList.remove(info.color);
      dataFromDiv.current
        .querySelectorAll("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .classList.add(warning.color);
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let timer;
    let timePassed = 0;
    let timeLeft;
    timer = counter > 0 && setTimeout(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);
    timePassed = timePassed += 1;
    timeLeft = counter - timePassed;
    setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);
    return () => {
      if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      }
    };
  }, [counter]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you were getting is because `dataFromDiv.current.querySelectorAll(...)` was always returning undefined because `dataFromDiv.current` was a reference to `div#base-timer-path-remaining` which is the element you wanted to modify. So, your code would work fine by just removing `.querySelectorAll(...)`.

However, there are some better ways to structure your code:

Instead of doing direct dom manipulations, it's easier in this case to just figure out which color you want using `useMemo` to set up derived data based on the counter value.

You can also use an interval instead of a timer as it's easier to work with and a little bit cleaner. This also uses the updater function form of setCounter so that the effect doesn't need to have `counter` in the dependencies.

I also added a reset button to my example below so you don't have to re-run it every time.

```
  const pathColor = React.useMemo(() => {
    const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
    if (counter <= alert.threshold) {
      return alert.color;
    } else if (counter <= warning.threshold) {
      return warning.color;
    } else {
      return info.color;
    }
  }, [counter]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter(counter => {
        if (counter <= 0) {
          clearInterval(timerId);
          return counter;
        }
        return counter - 1;
      });
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timerId);
    };
  }, [timerReset]); // this timerReset is to make sure that the interval starts off again whenever the reset button is pressed.
```

This line is simply a way to force a re-render. The reducer function `x=>x+1` increments the `timerReset` value whenever dispatch (renamed to `resetTimer`) is called. And then I use `timerReset` to force the effect to re-run in order to start the interval again (if it stopped)

```
  const [timerReset, resetTimer] = React.useReducer(x => x + 1, 0);
```

```js
const padTime = time => {
  return String(time).length === 1 ? `0${time}` : `${time}`;
};

const format = time => {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  const seconds = time % 60;
  return `${minutes}:${padTime(seconds)}`;
};

const WARNING_THRESHOLD = 10;
const ALERT_THRESHOLD = 5;

const COLOR_CODES = {
  info: {
    color: "green"
  },
  warning: {
    color: "orange",
    threshold: WARNING_THRESHOLD
  },
  alert: {
    color: "red",
    threshold: ALERT_THRESHOLD
  }
};

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(20);
  const [timerReset, resetTimer] = React.useReducer(x => x + 1, 0);
  const pathColor = React.useMemo(() => {
    const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
    if (counter <= alert.threshold) {
      return alert.color;
    } else if (counter <= warning.threshold) {
      return warning.color;
    } else {
      return info.color;
    }
  }, [counter]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter(counter => {
        if (counter <= 0) {
          clearInterval(timerId);
          return counter;
        }
        return counter - 1;
      });
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timerId);
    };
  }, [timerReset]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="base-timer">
        <svg
          className="base-timer__svg"
          viewBox="0 0 100 100"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <g className="base-timer__circle">
            <circle
              className="base-timer__path-elapsed"
              cx="50"
              cy="50"
              r="45"
            />
            <path
              id="base-timer-path-remaining"
              className={`base-timer__path-remaining ${pathColor}`}
              d="
          M 50, 50
          m -45, 0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
        "
            />
          </g>
        </svg>
        <span id="base-timer-label" className="base-timer__label">
          {format(counter)}
        </span>
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCounter(20);
          resetTimer();
        }}
      >
        reset timer
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}


const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```css
/* Sets the containers height and width */
.base-timer {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

/* Removes SVG styling that would hide the time label */
.base-timer__circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
}

/* The SVG path that displays the timer's progress */
.base-timer__path-elapsed {
  stroke-width: 7px;
  stroke: grey;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining {
  stroke-width: 7px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 1s linear all;
  fill-rule: nonzero;
  stroke: currentColor;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.green {
  color: rgb(65, 184, 131);
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.orange {
  color: orange;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.red {
  color: red;
}

.base-timer__label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
 <div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Zachary Haber

Comment: Hi @Zachary Haber can you tell  what exactly this line means i didn't get this ```const [timerReset, resetTimer] = React.useReducer(x => x + 1, 0);```

Comment: @Coding, I've added more detail about it in the body of the post (just before the snippet). Let me know if you have more questions

Comment: Hi @Zachary Haber just followed this blog for creating animated timer ```https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-animated-countdown-timer-with-html-css-and-javascript``` but its not working same can you please help if you got time.

Comment: I tried to create but nothing changes here is code https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-mountain-pdpto?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Coding, I've modified your code to get it working, https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-glitter-cslj2?file=/src/App.js. I put a lot of the comments I had about it in the sandbox. Main points are: try and avoid are doing direct dom mutations in React, and try to avoid using IDs if this is a component that you can use multiple of at the same time. If you need to do DOM mutations or get access to an element, use refs to get access to the elements you need to change.

Comment: I made it show a second timer as an example using different `initialTime`s :)